# Slider responsivo de texto en HTML5 y CSS3

Tags: html, css, scroll, slider, animacion-css

Hola amigos de Stack Overflow estoy realizando una página web con html y css y tengo que ponerle un pequeño slider que solo lleve texto, estuve investigando y vi que se puede hacer solo con css y su librería **animation** junto con **@keyframes** pero al ejecutarla me hace más grande mi página y muestra un scrollbar muy enorme tanto horizontal como vertical, como si el área de trabajo se expandiera, además encima los textos si lo ves de manera movil.
Ojala puedan ayudarme a resolverlo, les comparto mi página y también el código.
https://pruebasurologyq.000webhostapp.com/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: black;
}


#video-background { 
  position: fixed;
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto; 
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
}

article {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 3.0rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Raleway, sans serif;
 
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: Raleway, sans serif;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  padding: .4em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #3498db;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 30px;

}

.open {
  right: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  display: 
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}

.open:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.open:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.menuOpen {
  width: 24px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.menuOpen:hover .open:before {
  top: -9px;
}

.menuOpen:hover .open:after {
  top: 5px;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgb(76 62 95 / 90%);
}

.menu label {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background-size: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .menuContent {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: -260px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
  background: white;
}

.menuEffects {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0.5s;
}

.menuEffects ul {
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#menuToggle:checked ~ .menuEffects {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

#menuToggle:checked ~ .menuEffects ul {
  opacity: 1;
}

#menuToggle:checked ~ .menuOpen .open {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#menuToggle:checked ~ .menuOpen .open:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#menuToggle:checked ~ .menuOpen .open:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: white;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#menuToggle:not(:checked) ~ .menuEffects ul {
  transform: translateY(-30%);
}

.slider {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider ul {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    width: 400%;
    animation: cambio 30s infinite alternate linear;
}

.slider li {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}

.slider img {
    width: 100%;
}

@keyframes cambio {
    0% {margin-left: 0;}
    20% {margin-left: 0;}
    
    25% {margin-left: -100%;}
    45% {margin-left: -100%;}
    
    50% {margin-left: -200%;}
    70% {margin-left: -200%;}
    
    75% {margin-left: -300%;}
    100% {margin-left: -300%;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/background.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navbar.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slider.css">
        <title>UrologyQ</title>
    </head>

    <body>  
        <video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted>
            <source src="videos/background_video_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>


        <div id="menuArea">
            <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo">
            <input type="checkbox" id="menuToggle"></input>

            <label for="menuToggle" class="menuOpen">
              <div class="open"></div>
            </label>

                <div class="menu menuEffects">
                    <label for="menuToggle"></label>

                        <div class="menuContent">
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href="#">Sección 1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sección 2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sección 3</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sección 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slider">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h1>Tu urólogo de confianza</h1>
                 </li>
                <li>
                    <h1>Los tratamientos deben satisfacer tus necesidades</h1>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h1>¿Cirugía?, Solo si es estrictamente necesario</h1>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h1>Mi principal objetivo: Tu salud</h1>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: `body {overflow:hidden}` ocultará el scroll.

Comment: Ya lo intenté amigo pero al ejecutarlo en móvil se ve cómo se expande la página

Comment: Para eso existen las reglas css @media y los frameworks como Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

para evitar el scroll debes de quitar el min-height y el min-width y solo poner el width y height y poner el position en absolute

```
#video-background { 
 position: absolute;
 width: auto; 
 height: auto;
}
```

tambien tienes que cambiar el h1

```
h1{
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
}
```